# Finding all possible directed graphs given a number of vertices

Tags: graph, graph-theory, directed-graph

Is it possible to find all possible directed graphs given a pair of vertices and the information that an edge exists between them? For example if we know the vertices with edge pairs like

```
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

The possible directed graphs will be:

```
1→2, 2→3, 1→3 
1→2, 2→3, 3→1 
1→2, 3→2, 1→3 
1→2, 3→2, 3→1 
2→1, 2→3, 1→3 
2→1, 2→3, 3→1 
2→1, 3→2, 1→3 
2→1, 3→2, 3→1
```

What data-structure to be used here to work with? What can be the working logic?

I was thinking of using adjacency matrix data structure and compute all possible adjacency matrix. Each adjacency matrix will represent a graph. We can use the graph as and when needed for tasks like checking whether cycle is present or not etc.

**Apologies that this is more of a discussion than a programming question, but any help will be appreciated**

Comment: Each edge can extend one direction or the other, so looks like the answer is 2^n where ``n`` is the number of edges, assuming each edge is mono directional.

Comment: @user5994461 I actually didn't ask for the number of graphs obtained but the graphs so obtained.

Comment: This is not clear. "all possible directed graphs" that have what to do with a given "pair of vertices and the information that an edge exists between them"? Also your words disgree with your example input which is a set of vertex pairs, not a graph & a vertex pair. We can guess what you're trying to say & ask for confirmation but you should find how to say it.  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Otherwise you can't search for, ask about or code solutions.

Comment: What is your question? Discussions are off-topic. Asking for "approaches" is off-topic. You give no criteria to choose one approach over another. You are basically asking us to solve your problem without any effort by you. Work out as much of a solution as you can & ask one specific question re the first place you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain one undirected graph data structure G and work with the knowledge that the existence of an edge (u,v) means that there is only one directed edge in a particular instance of digraph possibility D.

If you want to maintain all possible digraphs separately, you would need 2^m many of them, where m is the number of edges. If the vertices and edges are always the same and only the direction is the invariant, then you could maintain 2^m bit-strings, each of length m. Each bit has a 0 or 1 depending on whether the edge (u,v) it corresponds to is u-->v or v<--u. Use the bit string to give direction to the undirected graph suggested above. You just need to generate all 2^m bit strings. Not very efficient... but you can't do better if you need to work with all possibilities.

You could use the bit string to construct a digraph. But, it would be more memory efficient at least to maintain only one bit-string per 'graph' rather than repeating the entire graph data structure with only directional changes. Record bit strings in a hash table: use each edge as a key and then bit value 0/1 depending on direction. Any graph traversal of one of the many possible digraphs D works on undirected G. Then in constant time you can check for incident (undirected) edges of a vertex, which are outgoing/incoming in D. So traversals can occur just as quickly by maintaining only 1 graph object and 1 bit hash table of size 2^m (rather than 2^m graph objects).

Comment: Great work. All possible bit-strings will give all possible directed graphs but I think it will be hard to determine whether a cycle in each directed graph then. My original task is to find whether each of these graphs is acyclic or not. I mean the logical part and it will be very easy if I actually maintain a graph data structure for each possibilities. Then I can easily find cycles using DFS algorithm. But that would be worst considering the time complexity. Your algorithm can be faster provided the logic is figured out. If you find out the algorithm please share, it will be of great help.